# How can I embed plotly graphs into powerpoints or apple's keynote?

Tags: plotly

I am learning how to generate graphs with plotly. I am biochemistry graduate student. I would like to use these graphs into presentations (e.g. powerpoint, keynote). I was wondering if someone could please give me a general strategy or link to a tutorial.

Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

Plotly has an MS Office App that allows embedding in Powerpoint on Windows computers:
https://store.office.com/plotly-charts-WA104379485.aspx?assetid=WA104379485

Keynote does not allow iframes, so Plotly graphs can't be embedded in Keynote.

Slides.com does allow iframes and works well with Plotly graphs:
http://slides.com/jackparmer/deck-3#/

Comment: Can PlotLy be embedded into PDF's?

Comment: What about the online Google Presentations?