# embedding a plotly image into a powerpoint using R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have made the following plotly image using the `plotly` and `ggplot2` packages in R

My question is, is there any way in which I can somehow copy/save this image into a powerpoint slide without losing its interactivity?

Here is all the code I've used to generate the plotly image.

```
library(rmsfuns)
packages <- c('ggplot2','ggthemes','lubridate',
              'readxl','plotly', 'dplyr','tidyr', 'scales', 'ggthemes')
load_pkg(packages)


p1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = as.Date(c("2018-01-01", "2019-10-01")), xmax = as.Date(c("2018-07-01", "2020-07-01")),
                ymin = 0, ymax = 70), fill = "red", alpha = 0.1, col = "red"
  ) +
  geom_line(data = pmi_data, aes(Date, Value), size = 1, col = "maroon") +
  labs(
    title = "Purchasing Manufacturing Index (PMI) - South Africa",
    subtitle = "Sharp Bounce in 2020 due to COVID-19",
    y = "Index Value", caption = "Data downloaded from Quantec,
                     Jan 2000 - Jul 2020 \n *Shaded areas indicate South African Recession Periods"
  ) +
  theme_solarized() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 50, col = "#0D7680", linetype = "dashed", size = 1) +
  geom_text(x = as.Date("2019-01-01"), y = 60, label = "Above 50 = Expansion") +
  geom_text(x = as.Date("2019-01-01"), y = 30, label = "Below 50 = Contraction") +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "3 months", date_labels = "%b-%y", limits = c(min, max)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 70, by = 10))

p1 %>% ggplotly() %>% 
  layout(title = list(text = paste0('ABSA Purchasing Managers\' Index (PMI) - Business Activity, South Africa',
                                    '<br>',
                                    '<sup>',
                                    'Manufacturing sentiment has rebounded following the strict lockdown measures imposed through April and May',
                                    '</sup>'))) %>% 
  layout(annotations = 
           list(x = 1, y = -0.08, text = "*Shaded areas denote South African recessions", 
                showarrow = F, xref='paper', yref='paper', 
                xanchor='right', yanchor='auto', xshift=0, yshift=0,
                font=list(size=15, color="grey90"))
  ) %>% 
  add_annotations(
    y = 65,
    text = 'Above 50 = Expansion',
    showarrow = F,
    col = 'black'
  ) %>% 
  add_annotations(
   y= 30,
  xref = "x",
  yref = "y",
  text = "Below 50 = Contraction",
  showarrow = F,
  ax = 20,
  ay = -40
)
```

and here is a reproductible of the dataset I've used (`pmi_data`)

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(16436, 16467, 16495, 16526, 
16556, 16587, 16617, 16648, 16679, 16709, 16740, 16770, 16801, 
16832, 16861, 16892, 16922, 16953, 16983, 17014, 17045, 17075, 
17106, 17136, 17167, 17198, 17226, 17257, 17287, 17318, 17348, 
17379, 17410, 17440, 17471, 17501, 17532, 17563, 17591, 17622, 
17652, 17683, 17713, 17744, 17775, 17805, 17836, 17866, 17897, 
17928, 17956, 17987, 18017, 18048, 18078, 18109, 18140, 18170, 
18201, 18231, 18262, 18293, 18322, 18353, 18383, 18414, 18444
), class = "Date"), Value = c(49.9309368121368, 58.6768073656206, 
45.7670083296354, 45.3051559795366, 39.0053846618642, 49.1441770833505, 
50.8080942369684, 51.5672278113692, 52.3474018054878, 48.684288238331, 
49.6005819277318, 41.8997241809938, 44.9937159943178, 35.9990124093785, 
43.1451562769853, 47.7227396808874, 52.890214035815, 51.5724155968251, 
53.098762758905, 48.5434650930155, 47.7228974417011, 50.4783047526896, 
45.8610689862814, 48.3232274365117, 48.528592558046, 49.3045039410955, 
51.2073193096086, 52.1261934198188, 35.2212207293696, 50.9496606483085, 
45.0422524998791, 38.0745271272649, 44.3456515676749, 46.1378825605808, 
47.6866697375406, 46.5994718651023, 43.9039427143585, 48.8655610360731, 
53.1107368639677, 46.5425509175865, 45.5076319096526, 46.8134977347412, 
46.4585946586574, 47.7383913350769, 40.2498176455257, 41.4636882678189, 
41.4500124747691, 48.0959672662869, 54.2532917453206, 48.0072394990694, 
42.6301974827825, 42.1455882001407, 47.0431096529903, 43.3389961678568, 
45.1685845453902, 55.0965589447133, 47.8335430001165, 41.0120070520458, 
45.6383412614183, 39.3644388865386, 36.6, 44.6, 33.7, 30.7, 5.1, 
43.2, 64.6)), row.names = c(NA, -67L), class = "data.frame")
```

TIA!

Comment: Hi OP - looks like there are very few options for you to do this while retaining interactivity.  There does appear to have existed an add-in for Powerpoint, but that means uploading your data to an online plot.ly account (not sure if you are comfortable doing that), and it also means you need an internet connection while presenting.  The second option is [referenced here](https://community.plotly.com/t/save-plotly-graphs-in-powerpoint-and-how-to-add-caption-in-graph/29361/5), which is to save the plot as a standalone HTML and launch that locally from your presentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I embed plotly graphs into powerpoints or apple's keynote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31305541/how-can-i-embed-plotly-graphs-into-powerpoints-or-apples-keynote)